# Free Electron Theory

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics, metals

If we consider a metal such that the lowest frequency electromagnetic radiation to which it is transparent is 2 x $10^{16}$ Hz. Now if the free electron density of the metal is doubled, what can be the minimum frequency to which it is transparent?

Logically I think that the new frequency must be lesser. But I have no idea about how to approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metals have a characteristic parameter called the plasma frequency $\omega_p^2 = \dfrac{ne^2}{m\epsilon_o}$ where $n$ is the free electron density and $m$ is the mass of an electron.
If the em radiation is below the plasma frequency the electrons oscillate at the frequency of the incoming radiation and the em radiation is reflected but above the plasma frequency the em radiation is transmitted because the electrons cannot respond fast enough to the incoming em radiation.